# Java Web sockets in Tomcat causing very High memory usage and OOO

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, websocket, spring-websocket

I am coding for an application that forms around 4 thousand connection and send data. but somehow it is consuming memory in more than 700 GB range. what is the ideal way to optimize? any Garbage collector suggestion that can help? even forcing GC on every message send is no help.

Goal is to test persistent long connection using web sockets on a large scale.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.websocket.Session;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.socket.CloseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.NativeWebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.TextWebSocketHandler;

import n1wsperf.server.ServerTelemetry.ServerMetricType;

@Component
public class TextSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    private volatile static HashMap<String, WebSocketSession> activeSessions = new HashMap<>() ;

    private static final int maxSizeInKB = 61440; // 60MB or 480Mb

    private static final TextMessage _data = DataService.getData();

    private static  String modeStr = "Request-Response";

    public static void Initialize() {
        Timer timer = new Timer("ActiveSessionTimer");
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ServerTelemetry.TrackMetric(ServerMetricType.ACTIVESESSION, activeSessions.size());
                System.out.println("Active Connections : " + activeSessions.size());
            }
        };
        CompletableFuture.runAsync( () -> { timer.schedule(task, 1000, 60000L); });
    }

    public TextSocketHandler() {
        modeStr = ServerConfig.getServerRunConfig().DuplexMode ? "Duplex" : "Request-Response";
    }

    @Async
    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        try {
            session.setTextMessageSizeLimit(maxSizeInKB * 1024); // 60MB or 480Mb
            String sessionId = session.getId();
            if (session instanceof NativeWebSocketSession) {
                final Session nativeSession = ((NativeWebSocketSession)session).getNativeSession(Session.class); 
                if (nativeSession != null ) {
                    nativeSession.getUserProperties()
                         .put("org.apache.tomcat.websocket.BLOCKING_SEND_TIMEOUT", 60_000L);
                }
            }
            session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(sessionId));
            activeSessions.putIfAbsent(session.getId(), session);
            ServerTelemetry.TrackMetric(ServerMetricType.NEWSESSION);
            TraceLogger.Info("SocketHandler", String.format("Session(new): %s: Mode: %s: New Connection established with client %s", session.getId(), modeStr,session.getRemoteAddress()), true);

            Run run = ServerConfig.getServerRunConfig();
            if (run.DuplexMode){
                startDuplexCommunicationAsync(sessionId, run);          // non-blocking
            }
            TraceLogger.Info("SocketHandler", String.format("Session (Verbose: %s): %s: Mode: %s Communication is in progress with client %s", run.Verbose, session.getId(), modeStr,session.getRemoteAddress()), true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            ServerTelemetry.TrackMetric(ServerMetricType.FAILEDSESSION);
            ServerTelemetry.TrackException(e);
            TraceLogger.Error("SocketHandler", String.format("Session: %s Mode: %s Exception: %s", session.getId(), modeStr,e.getMessage()));
        } finally {
            System.gc();
        }
    }
    
    @Async
    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        try{
        var sessionId = session.getId();
        var clientAdr = session.getRemoteAddress();

        ServerTelemetry.TrackMetric(ServerMetricType.CLOSEDSESSION);
        TraceLogger.Info("SocketHandler", String.format("Session: %s Mode: %s : Closed Connection with client %s", sessionId, modeStr,clientAdr), true);
        if (activeSessions.keySet().contains(sessionId)){
            activeSessions.remove(sessionId);
            ServerTelemetry.TrackMetric(ServerMetricType.ACTIVESESSION, activeSessions.size());
        }}
        finally {
            System.gc();
        }
    }

    @Async
    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
        try {
            String sessionId = session.getId();
            WebSocketSession wsSession = activeSessions.get(sessionId);

            long start = System.nanoTime();
            //ServerTelemetry.TrackMetric(ServerMetricType.REQUEST);
            String payload = message.getPayload();
            //ServerTelemetry.TrackMetric(ServerMetricType.REQUESTSIZE, payload.length());  // Bytes
            TraceLogger.Info("SocketHandler", String.format("Session: %s: Mode: %s: Received %s bytes from client %s", sessionId, modeStr,payload.length(), wsSession.getRemoteAddress()));
            
            if (!ServerConfig.getServerRunConfig().DuplexMode) {
                CompletableFuture.runAsync( () -> {
                    try {
                        sendMessage(wsSession, start);
                    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                        TraceLogger.Error("SocketHandler", String.format("Session: %s Mode: %s Exception: %s", sessionId, modeStr,e.getMessage()));
                    } 
                }).get();
            }

            long end = System.nanoTime();
            double reqDurationms = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(end - start);

           // ServerTelemetry.TrackMetric(ServerMetricType.ACTIVESESSION, activeSessions.size());
           // ServerTelemetry.TrackMetric(ServerMetricType.DURATION, reqDurationms);

            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ServerTelemetry.TrackMetric(ServerMetricType.FAILEDREQUEST);
            ServerTelemetry.TrackException(e);
            TraceLogger.Error("SocketHandler", String.format("Session: %s Mode: %s Exception: %s", session.getId(), modeStr,e.getMessage()));
        } finally {
            System.gc();
        }

    }
    
    @Async
    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(WebSocketSession session, Throwable exception) throws Exception {
        try{
        WebSocketSession wsSession = activeSessions.get(session.getId());

        ServerTelemetry.TrackMetric(ServerMetricType.TRANSPORTERROR);
        TraceLogger.Error("SocketHandler", String.format("Session: %s: Mode: %s Error: %s", wsSession.getId(), modeStr,exception.getMessage()));
        if (activeSessions.keySet().contains(wsSession.getId())){
            activeSessions.remove(wsSession.getId());
            ServerTelemetry.TrackMetric(ServerMetricType.ACTIVESESSION, activeSessions.size());
        }}
        finally {
            System.gc();
        }
    }

    private void startDuplexCommunicationAsync(String sessionId, Run run) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            long sessionStart = System.nanoTime();
            WebSocketSession wsSession = null;
            for (long current = System.nanoTime(); current < sessionStart + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(run.KeepAlive_Sec);  ){
                try {
                    wsSession = activeSessions.get(sessionId);
                    sendMessage(wsSession, System.nanoTime());
                    current = System.nanoTime();
                } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                    TraceLogger.Error("SocketHandler", String.format("Session: %s Mode: %s Exception: %s", sessionId, modeStr,e.getMessage()));
                }
            }
            if (wsSession != null && wsSession.isOpen()){
                try {
                    wsSession.close(CloseStatus.NORMAL);
                    TraceLogger.Info("SocketHandler", String.format("Session: %s Mode: %s: Closing session as the configured keepalive duration (%s seconds) has elapsed, sent session close to client %s", sessionId, modeStr,run.KeepAlive_Sec, wsSession.getRemoteAddress()), true);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    TraceLogger.Error("SocketHandler", String.format("Session: %s Mode: %s Exception: %s", sessionId, modeStr,e.getMessage()));
                }
            }
        });
        
    }

    private void sendMessage(WebSocketSession session, long start) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if (!session.isOpen()) {
            throw new IOException("Session is not in open state");
        }

        var runCfg = ServerConfig.getServerRunConfig();

        try {
            session.sendMessage(_data);
            
            //ServerTelemetry.TrackMetric(ServerMetricType.RESPONSESIZE, _data.getPayloadLength());  // Bytes
            TraceLogger.Info("SocketHandler", String.format("Session: %s: Mode: %s: %s bytes sent to client %s", session.getId(), modeStr, _data.getPayloadLength(), session.getRemoteAddress()));

            long end = System.nanoTime();
            long remainMillis = runCfg.RequestInterval_ms - TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(end - start);
            if (remainMillis > 0) {
                Thread.sleep(remainMillis);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            TraceLogger.Error("SocketHandler", String.format("Session: %s: Mode: %s: Exception: %s", session.getId(), modeStr,e.getMessage()));
        } finally {
            System.gc();
        }

    }

}
```

1. Various kinds of GC, parallel with 50% GC time, still on execution, available memory went to zero
2. Removing logging

Comment: what are the thread limits for this server?

Comment: kept it between 2000 to 4000, already letting the application use available memory by 95% of the systme which is around 678GB

Answer (score 1):

From a quick overview of your TextSocketHandler code, I can highlight a few points that may help in optimizing memory usage and avoiding potential memory leaks:

- HashMap for Active Sessions: The use of activeSessions to store WebSocket sessions might lead to memory concerns if the sessions are not properly removed when closed. Ensure that sessions are removed from the activeSessions map upon closure to prevent memory leaks.
- Async Operations and Error Handling: Be cautious with the usage of CompletableFuture.runAsync() within the WebSocket methods (afterConnectionEstablished, afterConnectionClosed, handleTextMessage, handleTransportError). These async operations might introduce contention and potential memory overhead if not managed effectively.
- Garbage Collection: Invoking System.gc() explicitly within your WebSocket methods may not be necessary and can be counterproductive, as Java's garbage collector is designed to manage memory automatically.
- Resource Handling: Always ensure that resources such as WebSocket sessions are properly closed and cleaned up when they are no longer needed. This includes closing the sessions, handling exceptions properly, and releasing any resources associated with the sessions.
- Data Processing and Buffering: Consider optimizing the processing of incoming and outgoing messages (handleTextMessage, sendMessage) to minimize memory usage. Evaluate if large payloads or data structures are being unnecessarily retained in memory.

**To optimize memory usage and avoid potential issues:**

- Verify that sessions are correctly removed from activeSessions when closed.
- Review the asynchronous operations and ensure proper error handling and resource cleanup.
- Avoid unnecessary explicit garbage collection calls (System.gc()).
- Evaluate how data is processed and handled within WebSocket methods to minimize memory footprint.

It's important to profile your application under load to identify memory hotspots and areas causing high memory consumption. Tools like Java Flight Recorder, VisualVM, or profilers can assist in identifying memory leaks or inefficient memory usage patterns in your WebSocket code.